# Proof that length of opposite side to angle bisector is $p=bc/(a+b)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, bisection

Given triangle $ABC$ with angle $C$ bisected to meet side $c$, we have the following sides of the triangle: $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $p$, and $q$ where $x$ is the angle bisector, $p+q=c$ (the two divisions created by the angle bisector.

We are expected to prove that $p=bc/(a+b)$ and (for the other triangle) $q=ac/(a+b)$. This likely uses LoS or LoC, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Do you know the angle bisector theorem? Start with $a/p = b/q$

Comment: I started with $p/c=q/a$ (my triangle swapped p and q) and got only to $p=c(q/a)$. Since I'm supposed to end with $p=cb/(b+c)$ I assume somehow $q/a=b/(b+c)$.

Comment: You also have $p+q=c$ as the other equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Triangle diagram]

Start off with the internal bisector theorem...
$$\begin{align}\dfrac ba&=\dfrac pq\\\dfrac ab&=\dfrac qp\\\dfrac{a+b}b&=\dfrac{p+q}p\qquad(\text{Componendo})\\\dfrac{a+b}b&=\dfrac cp\\p&=\dfrac{bc}{a+b}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $p$ and $q$ as solutions to the following system of quations

$$ \begin{cases} p+q = c \\\\ \dfrac{p}{b} = \dfrac{q}{a} \end{cases} $$

The easiest way is to solve for one variable in terms of the other and pug it into the other equation. For example, using $q= c-p$ we get

$$ \frac{p}{b} =\frac{c-p}{a} = \frac{c}{a}- \frac{p}{a} $$
$$ \frac{p}{a} + \frac{p}{b}= \frac{c}{a} $$
$$ p\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} \right)= \frac{c}{a} $$
$$ p \cdot\frac{a+b}{ab}= \frac{c}{a} $$
$$ b = \frac{bc}{a+b} $$

Althernatively, you can also use $q = \dfrac{ap}{b}$ to get
$$ p + \frac{ap}{b} = c $$
$$ p \left(1 + \frac{a}{b} \right) = c $$
$$ p \cdot \frac{a+b}{b}= c $$
$$ p = \frac{bc}{a+b} $$